# How can I convert any nested lists to tuples?

Tags: python, list, tuples

Input:

```
(
    ("Alfred", ["gaming", "shopping", "sport", "travel"]),
    (
        "Carmen",
        [
            "cooking",
            "pets",
            "photography",
            "shopping",
            "sport",
        ],
    ),
)
```

How can I convert any list inside this list (or further depth) to a tuple?

Expected output:

```
(
    ("Alfred", ("gaming", "shopping", "sport", "travel")),
    (
        "Carmen",
        (
            "cooking",
            "pets",
            "photography",
            "shopping",
            "sport",
        ),
    ),
)
```

Comment: The same way you do with any list->tuple, except that you're going to have to remake the parent tuple because tuples are immutable.

Comment: `tuple((l[0], tuple(l[1])) for l in ip)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to assume your original data is in a variable named `t`

```py
t = tuple((item[0], tuple(item[1])) for item in t)
```

This uses `tuple()` to convert the list (or any iterable) into a tuple.

Docs: https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=tuple#tuple